# Problems with fprintf format (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, import, printing, format, fopen

I want to correct variables' format in a txt file (show at the end, replace spaces for tab spaces),  using the next Matlab code (previous import):

```
id = fopen('datoscorfecha.txt', 'w');
fprintf(id, '%5s %3s %3s %3s %4s %3s %6s\n',...
'fecha', 'dia','mes', 'ano', 'hora', 'min', 'abs370');

datos = cat(2,dia, mes, ano, hora, min1, abs370);
datos = datos';
fecha = Fecha'; % Imported as a string 

fprintf(id, '%16s %2i %2i %4i %2i %2i %8.4f\n',...
    fecha, datos);
    
fclose(id);
type datoscorfecha.txt
```

But I get this error:

Error using fprintf
Unable to convert 'string' value to
'int64'.

---

Fecha   dia mes ano hora    min abs370

03/06/2016 00:00    3   6   2016    0   0   29.356218

03/06/2016 00:05    3   6   2016    0   5   30.45703

03/06/2016 00:10    3   6   2016    0   10  27.53877

03/06/2016 00:15    3   6   2016    0   15  23.19832

03/06/2016 00:20    3   6   2016    0   20  22.333924

03/06/2016 00:25    3   6   2016    0   25  22.086426

03/06/2016 00:30    3   6   2016    0   30  20.933898

Comment: Please read [mre]. The error complains about the contents of `fecha` and/or `datos`, but we don’t know what these variables contain.

Comment: @CrisLuengo . Please read all the question.

Comment: I’ve read the whole question. I can’t run your code, I can’t tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo. I explicit all variables, and the delimitator, so I don't know what you need. Maybe you need to import (using the Matlab interface) and then use the code. Please check it out.

Comment: The line `datos = cat(2,dia, mes, ano, hora, min1, abs370);` has 6 undefined variables. The part at the bottom of the post does not define how these variables are defined: are they all strings? Is one a `datetime` object and the other doubles? Are some ints? Are these numeric arrays or cell arrays? Please write **code** that assigns some values to these variables so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: What I understand is that you imported the variables from a `.mat` file by clicking on them from the side panel. Can you please tell us the data types of the variables. You'll be able to see the data types on the right side "workspace" panel.

Comment: As Cris suggested maybe creating arrays that mimick the arrays you have imported will allow us to test the code. (pseudo/test inputs).

Comment: @MichaelTr7. I import the data from a txt file not a mat file. You can do it clicking in 'Import Options' from 'Home'. I'm using Matlab 2020a. Maybe that's the reason you can't import it.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the text file in your question it will be very helpful?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 I did it

Comment: Oh that bottom half is the `.txt` file?

Comment: @MichaelTr7. How can I attach a txt here?

Comment: By simply pasting it. Is that second half of your question the text in the `.txt` file or is that the expected output of your MATLAB script?

Comment: @MichaelTr7. That's the content, I don't get an output because the error.

Comment: @MichaelTr7. Sure. Althought the result is the same, because I think so that Matlab find out the delimiter automatically.

Comment: Please only constructive feedback, because in other hand it will be long to read and unuseful for other users interested in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can allow you to replace the spaces with tabs. Here I read the text file using the `textscan()` function and separate the columns. I also parse each value/term as a string. By using the `writematrix()` function I can write the data to a new text file the but with the `Delimeter` set to `tab`.

### Text.txt (Input)

```
Fecha dia mes ano hora min abs370
03/06/2016 00:00 3 6 2016 0 0 29.356218
03/06/2016 00:05 3 6 2016 0 5 30.45703
03/06/2016 00:10 3 6 2016 0 10 27.53877
03/06/2016 00:15 3 6 2016 0 15 23.19832
03/06/2016 00:20 3 6 2016 0 20 22.333924
03/06/2016 00:25 3 6 2016 0 25 22.086426
03/06/2016 00:30 3 6 2016 0 30 20.933898
```

---

### datoscorfecha.txt (Output)

```
Fecha   dia mes ano hora    min abs370  
03/06/2016  00:00   3   6   2016    0   0   29.3562
03/06/2016  00:05   3   6   2016    0   5   30.4570
03/06/2016  00:10   3   6   2016    0   10  27.5388
03/06/2016  00:15   3   6   2016    0   15  23.1983
03/06/2016  00:20   3   6   2016    0   20  22.3339
03/06/2016  00:25   3   6   2016    0   25  22.0864
03/06/2016  00:30   3   6   2016    0   30  20.9339
```

---

### Full Script:

```
File_ID = fopen("Text.txt");

Data = textscan(File_ID, '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s', 'Delimiter',' ');
fclose(File_ID);

% Data = readtable("Text.txt");
Column_1 = string(Data{:,1});
Column_2 = string(Data{:,2});
Column_3 = string(Data{:,3});
Column_4 = string(Data{:,4});
Column_5 = string(Data{:,5});
Column_6 = string(Data{:,6});
Column_7 = string(Data{:,7});
Column_8 = string(Data{:,8});

for Index = 2: length(Column_8)

Number = str2double(char(Column_8(Index,1)));
Number = num2str(Number);
Decimal_String = split(Number,".");
Decimal_String = Decimal_String{2};

if length(Decimal_String) ~= 4
Number = string(Number) + "0";
end

Column_8(Index,1) = Number;
    
end

Table = [Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4 Column_5 Column_6 Column_7 Column_8];
writematrix(Table,"datoscorfecha.txt",'Delimiter','tab');

type datoscorfecha.txt
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thanks because I didn't know this way of import and export data, but this answer has nothing to do with my question. I want to correct variables' format, specifically the last column, where floating point number change between rows.

Comment: What type did you want the last column formatted as?

Comment: You want only 4 decimal places?

Comment: Yes, I do, because I'm using Matlab to correct txt data previous import in Fortran. I need a regular output's structure.

Comment: I updated the code to only include 4 decimal points.

Comment: Thanks so much. I see, using string is better. But my question was why does not fprintf works properly?

Comment: It was trying to print a string or char variable as int I think and the types didn’t match.

Comment: 'fecha' is a string and I'm using  "fprintf(id, '%16s %..."

Comment: I think it's having problems with the other variables.